# FragmentActivity - Zoom to show streets

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm having some issues using FragmentActivity and SupportMapFragment. The map's zoom is all wonky. 
Here's the code:

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends FragmentActivity{
Double longitude, latitude;
static LatLng koordinate;
GoogleMap supportMap;
String title, address;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_googlemaps);
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMap = fm.getMap();

    longitude = 13.597651720046997;
    latitude = 45.22456639103469;
    title = "Turistička zajednica Općine Vrsar";
    address = "ul. Rade Končara 46";
    koordinate = new LatLng(longitude, latitude);

    Marker marker = supportMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(koordinate).title(title).snippet(address)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_star)));
    //supportMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    supportMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(koordinate, 15));
    supportMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);   
}}
```

For some reason, I get following thing in google maps, which is not zoomed enough:
http://imageshack.us/f/812/3yl.png/
When I click on the zoom, the map goes into this state:
http://imageshack.us/f/825/k8np.png/

I need the maps to zoom enough so that the street names are shown.This works just fine in my previous application, but I used regular MapFragment there. For this app, I need SupportMapFragment. Maybe that's causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom in the Google Map

```
  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

OR

```
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
// Showing the current location in Google Map
  googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

the maximum zoom allowed is 17 i guess.
i hope this must work...

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces the same result as the second picture.

Comment: ashish.n, that just loads a blue map (maybe over water?), because that line moves the camera to specified coordinates.

Comment: it might be ... use known lat long...use latitude = 33.7489  longitude = -84.3881... this are for Atlanta

Comment: Says I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: you can choose this as an answer